# Future Builder don't show data from Cloud Firestore

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I load data from Cloud Firestore from Firebase. In the print statement in the function loadAssignments() the loaded data are showing correct. But when i will show the data in the Text widget with the widget FutureBuilder it doesn't show the data and i don't know why. Can anyone please help me?

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';

class AssignmentPage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _AssignmentPageState createState() => _AssignmentPageState();
}

class _AssignmentPageState extends State<AssignmentPage> {
  Future _loadAssignments;
  QuerySnapshot _assignments;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _loadAssignments = loadAssignments();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Bühlmaier App'),
        centerTitle: true,
        automaticallyImplyLeading: false,
      ),
      body: FutureBuilder(
        future: _loadAssignments,
        builder: (context, snapshot) {
          if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done) {
            return ListView.builder(
                itemCount: _assignments.documents.length,
                itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                  return Card(
                    child: ListTile(
                      leading: Text('${_assignments.documents[index].data['Name'].toString()}'),
                    ),
                  );
                });
          } else if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
            return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
          }
          return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
        },
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        child: Icon(Icons.add),
        onPressed: () => toPage(NewAssignmentPage()),
      ),
    );
  }

  Future<void> loadAssignments() async {
    _assignments = await Firestore.instance.collection('assignments').getDocuments();
    for (int i = 0; i < _assignments.documents.length; i++) {
      print('DATEN: ' + _assignments.documents[i].data['Name'].toString());
    }
    setState(() {});
  }
}
```

When i add the following code:

```
else if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
        return Text("No data");
      }
```

it works, but when i edit the code to:

```
else if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
            return CircularProgressIndicator();
          }
```

it don't load the data and the CircularProgressIndicator() is not moving.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the method in the `future` property:

```
          FutureBuilder(
            future: loadAssignments(),
            builder: (context, AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot> snapshot) {
              if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done) {
                return ListView.builder(
                    shrinkWrap: true,
                    itemCount: snapshot.data.documents.length,
                    itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                  return Card(
                    child: ListTile(
                      leading: Text('${snapshot.data.documents[index].data['Name'].toString()}'),
                    ),
                  );
                    });
              } else if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.none) {
                return Text("No data");
              }
              return CircularProgressIndicator();
            },
          ),
```

Change the method to the following:

```
  Future<QuerySnapshot> loadAssignments() async {
    return await Firestore.instance.collection('assignments').getDocuments();
  }
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but the result is the same. The data is not loading. When i comment out the if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done) it loads the data, but before the data is loading it shows a red error screen on my phone.

Comment: is there any error? Is this showing `CircularProgressIndicator`?

Comment: The CircularProgressIndicator don't load it shows only a little bit from the CircularProgressIndicator, but it doesnt move.

Comment: I have copy your code and it works when i add the code above (see Question). With Text "No data" it works but not with CircularProgessIndicator. I have no idee why you?

Comment: Don't use waiting, just use it same as my code if connectionstate.done then get the data if connectionstate.none then no date and return CircularProgressIndicator(). By adding return CircularProgressIndicator() as in my code it should first show the progress indicator then it will either show no data or the listview